# CaptureFromFile in OpenCV on Android in Java

Tags: java, android, opencv

Maybe I'm being a bit slow, but I can't find the equivalent of CaptureFromFile for grabbing video frames one by one from a file in OpenCV in Java on Android.

Can anyone put me out of my misery please and show me where to look?

Many thanks

Barry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCV does not support video reading/writing on Android yet.

Comment: Thanks Andrey, I thought I was losing my mind when I couldn't find it. Do you happen to know when a new release might support video files?

Comment: I don't expect video support in next major release.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at solution in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337505/android-capture-video-frame). Also, it seems like Open CV is available thrue Android NDK, [here](http://www.stanford.edu/~zxwang/android_opencv.html) you may find how to use it. In addition, you may take a look at [Processing](http://processing.org/), which i believe supports Open CV and able to export code as apk.

Comment: Thanks Gökhan, from what Andrey said I'm going to have to find another route :/