# To capture frame from video

Tags: android, video, video-streaming, frame, video-capture

I want to implement the functionality which will  do the video recording but instead of saving the video I want to save the frames of video from that recording.How to do it

Comment: Maybe you can use camera class: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

Comment: see this ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337505/android-capture-video-frame

Answer (score 0):

If the aim is to create jpegs of the video Camera class will not be of much help here. It captures videos or jpegs. Does not do any conversion.

If you want a full video to be converted to a set of images then simplest way is to use ffmpeg. Install it. After creating the video run a command after capturing the video and convert it to images.

```
ffmpeg -i input -s widthxheight -f image2 out%05d.jpg
```

that will create out00000.jpg out00001.jpg and so on from the video. You can use the -r option to generate every second frame or 10th frame and so on.