# how can I create a thumbnail of a video url in android?

Tags: java, android, image

I have a problem, I can only create thumbnails of local video files but not of a remote url, here is my code:

```
bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail("http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4", MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND), 50, 50);
```

I hope you can help me,

regards
christian

Comment: I guess you need to download the video first

Comment: You need to download the image and then display it in imageview. I guess that should help you. To download you can use asynctask.

Comment: You will have to capture a frame and then display the thumbnail with it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337505/android-capture-video-frame. If you can download a image form url then you can display the it in imageview. Otherwise download a part of the image, capture a frame and display the thubnail.

Comment: @Raghunandan but you need to download the video before  capturing any frame...

Comment: @fiddler i agree with you. typing mistake. To display a frame you need to download the video.

Comment: This can be helpful :
[See This Stack's Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32689023/6067690)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose there is no easy way to build the thumbnail without actually downloading the video locally.

So if your question is 'Can I get a thumbnail without having to download the full video?', I'd say...no.

Otherwise, once you have downloaded the video locally, then I guess you can perfectly use `ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(...)` by giving the path to the downloaded file.

Answer (score 5):

I also have the same problem - but what can I say from my tests:

1. The problem occurs only on android >2.3
2. in android 2.0 -> 2.3 You can use just

`Bitmap thumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail( videoUrl, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);`

I hope someone explain what change is on android 4. it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

I have no problem generating thumbnails from remote videos with the following code:

`final Bitmap thumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail( videoUrl, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND );`

You don't have to wrap an `extractThumbnail()` call around it